# How to force Stop terraform commands execution?

Tags: bash, terraform

I have a bash script that runs different terraform commands. 
Like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    terraform init -force-copy
    terraform destroy -auto-approve -var-file=terraform.tfvars

    # Removes workspace and files from local
    terraform workspace select default
    terraform workspace delete -force $project_name
```

I want my script to run command terraform destroy and then check if terraform destroy is successful. If successful then only Removes workspace and files.

Right now if my terraform destroy fails it still runs workspace commands which I don't want when it fails.

Comment: If `teraform` has a useful exit status then  `if terraform destroy .....; then teraform ....; fi`

Comment: @Jetchisel It does have a useful exit status so you should provide that as an answer or even link to a duplicate if appropriate.

Comment: I'll leave it here.

Comment: I am looking for the same some useful exit status. It will be great if you can provide me with some link :)